# Monitoring Windows Service Activities

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have created a Windows Service which performs certain tasks, like archiving files, sending them via FTP, etc.

I have also created a System Tray Icon, which I'd like to show the current activity of the Windows Service.

I know about custom commands which allow to communicate with Windows Services, but don't like this approach. Is there any recommended way of achieving this?

Comment: That depends on *what* communicates with the service

Comment: e.g. a WinForms application. It would display a text notifying about current activity of the Windows Service. something like that...

Comment: Then I'd recommend WCF, hosted in the Windows Service, called from the WnForms application (possibly using NamedPipes)

Comment: Seconding @cFrozenDeath's suggestion--use the [NetNamedPipeBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx) binding if you go this route.

Comment: OK, I see. And, what about anonymous pipes? Both applications are (and always will be) on the same machine. And I think I'd better implement something custom (and primitive), with less overhead. Thanks for your suggestions!